# Allow "shop manager" to delete users account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, user-roles

I want to know what part of code should I edit to allow the shop manager in a wordpress website to delete any users account?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add `'delete_users'` capability to the Shop manager user role we use `admin_init` hook, `get_role()` and `add_cap()` functions.

Use this php code snippet (paste it in the `function.php` file of your active child theme or theme):

```
function shop_manager_delete_users_cap() {
    // gets the user role
    $role = get_role( 'shop_manager' );

    // Add the new capability 
    $role->add_cap( 'delete_users' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'shop_manager_delete_users_cap');
```

Comment: This is not working anymore. You can see the option but the action is not allowed.

Comment: @MatijaŽiberna It does work. I just tested it myself on WC 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to allow shop manager to delete users accounts then you need to add capabilities for shop manager role. Below plugin will allow you to add specific capabilities for wordpress roles. You need to add user access to shop manager using this plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/screenshots/